# listing multiple versions on pypi

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, package-managers, setup.py

I am using setup.py / distutils to distribute a package. How can multiple released versions of a py package be listed on pypi using setup.py/distutils?  right now when I submit the latest version, it replaces all previous versions on the pypi package page and restarts the # downloads counter.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Log in to PyPi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=login), select your package, you can choose to show older releases and/or disable the auto-hide feature.